# Extension $C^{k}_{c}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ to $C^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, distribution-theory

I have some difficulties in proving the following theorem:

Let $f\in C_{c}^{k}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Let $\rho\in C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be such that
$$\rho\geq0,\,\ \mbox{supp}\, \rho\subset\{|x|\leq 1\},\, \int\rho\, dx=1.$$ Let $\varepsilon>0$ and put 
$$f_{\varepsilon}(x)=\varepsilon^{-n}\int f(y)\rho (\frac{x-y}{\varepsilon})dy.$$ Then $f_{\varepsilon}\in C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and the support is of $f_{\varepsilon}$ is contained in the $\varepsilon$ - neighbourhood of the support $f$, moreover, if $|\alpha|\leq k$, then $\partial^{\alpha}f_{\varepsilon}$ converge uniformly to $\partial^{\alpha}f$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$.

The first statement is obvious, i.e., $f_{\varepsilon}\in C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Why the support  of $f_{\varepsilon}$ is contained in the $\varepsilon$ - neighbourhood of the support $f$? In order to prove the convergance, I consider $k=0$ at first. Let $z=(x-y)/\varepsilon$. Then
$$y=x-\varepsilon\cdot x,\,\, dy=-\varepsilon dz.$$
So
$$f_{\varepsilon}(x)=-\varepsilon^{-n+1}\int f(x-\varepsilon z)\rho(z)dz$$ and
$$|f_{\varepsilon}(x)-f(x)|=|\varepsilon^{-n+1}|\cdot |\int(\frac{f(x)}{\varepsilon^{-n+1}}-f_{\varepsilon}(x-\varepsilon z))\rho (z)dz|.$$
What should be done next?

Comment: Hint: If $x$ is not in the $\varepsilon$-neighbourhood of the support of $f$, then the integrand is identically zero – either one, or the other, of the two factors must vanish. Key here is that $\rho((x-y)/\varepsilon\ne0$ only if $|x-y|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: You made a mistake in the change of variables. In $\mathbb{R}^n$, you'd get $dy=\varepsilon ^n\,dz$. Remember, $dy$ here is really short for $dy_1\cdot dy_2\cdots dy_n$, and ditto for $dx$. And there is no minus sign, since we're not doing signed integration here. You should get $f_\varepsilon(x)=\int f(x-\varepsilon z)\rho(z)\,dz$. Next, there is a trick: Write $f(x)=\int f(x)\rho(z)\,dz$, then subtract.

Comment: I didn't notice what I had written - supp $\rho \subset \{|x|\le 1\}$. Now it is clear to me.